# How can I automatically prepend a column to a table (tabular environment) globally?

Tags: tables

Let's say I make my own tabular environment wrapper.

Can I automatically prepend a column globally to all tables using my custom tabular environment?

## Sample Tabular Input

```
localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
```

## Desired Tabular Output for Typesetting

```
globalcol1 & localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
globalcol2 & localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
globalcol3 & localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
```

## Code

I really have no idea how to do this. I suspect maybe the `array` package, but here is some code to get started:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% xelatex

\newenvironment{mytabular}
  {\leavevmode\begin{tabular}{lll}
  % <== insert global column here
  }
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{mytabular}
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
col1 & col2 & col3 \\
\end{mytabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Will your global column always have the same number of rows at the local columns?

Comment: @Werner If I understand you correctly, the number of rows is arbitrary. I think that is necessary for flexibility here. I realize that some value must be set for each global cell. I suppose I would like the flexibility to set some global cell values. Those not set will be empty strings. I have not thought that through, however. e.g. A table might have 10 rows. Maybe the global column cell values would be row indexes, but only up to 5. The 5 remaining cell values will be empty strings. Does that seem reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepend a single-column `tabular` to the left of your `mytabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{mytabular}
  {\noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ l }
    globalcol1 \\
    globalcol2 \\
    globalcol3
  \end{tabular}\begin{tabular}[t]{ l l l }
  }
  {\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytabular}
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3
\end{mytabular}

\bigskip

\begin{mytabular}
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3 \\
  localcol1 & localcol2 & localcol3
\end{mytabular}

\end{document}
```

Using a `[t]`op alignment ensures that a different number of columns will still line up vertically. A problem may arise if your row heights differ. However, using an `l`-column will not allow wrapping, and therefore would maintain a consistent baseline.

Comment: My only issue is the baseline. I mostly use the `p` type. your answers meets my needs for now though.